# Is there any jQuery plugin which display an horizontal accordion showing half images?

Tags: jquery

Basically I need one like this:

http://yogafasting.org/

First, it displays a partial image and then when you hover it, it shows the full image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example looks exactly like this one,

http://www.alohatechsupport.net/webdesignmaui/maui-web-site-design/create_image_menu_with_jquery.html

And here is a link to the demo
http://www.alohatechsupport.net/examples/image-menu-1.html

Comment: Yes it looks exactly the same. Thanks.